# How to obtain the expected TPS., which is calculated by parameters value?

Tags: performance, concurrency, jmeter, throughput, tps

I have used the normal thread group of 40 threads,180000 of throughput, and expected TPS is 3000.., But , Resulted only 2750 tps., How can I improve the TPS?
I have tried the concurrency thread group along with the shaping timer combination..
Can u pls guide me..,Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

TPS or the throughput is controlled by sending the required number of requests to the target server in a unit time (seconds, minutes, hours, etc)

It is not easy or good practice to control the throughput by changing the number of threads. When the server gets slow the throughput gets low and vice-versa.

You need to introduce delays when the server responds faster and introduce more threads when the server responds slower. It is not easy to achieve the desired throughput by setting the thread count.

Please note that

> throughput will be lower if the server is not capable of handling it, or if other timers or time-consuming test elements prevent it.

JMeter has a number of ways to achieve the desired throughput by introducing delays to the requests.

Using Timers

- [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
- [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)
- [Througput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

In the above cases, you need to ensure a sufficient number of threads are available to generate the required throughputs. This solution is not efficient if a large number of threads are created than the required number of threads.

The best approach would be the test should create additional threads on-demand and introduce delays between requests as required.

In JMeter, you can achieve this with [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) along with the [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/).

[This video](https://youtu.be/D3wu69xwIPU) demonstrate the use of the controllers.

Comment: I have checked with concurrency thread Group along with throughput shaping timer. If i define a value for 3000 tps.,It results the output upto 2700 tps. So, No improvement when i tried the above.[It starts from 13k tps and gradually reducing tps count as time moves: This is the result for concurrency thread group without timer].

Comment: And The CPU utilization is 80 percent when I have tried for concurrency in thread group.

Comment: Initially, I have used Precise throughput timer. Throughput:180000, Ramp up period 200, Expected TPS=(180000/60=3000), Resulted TPS=2700 tps (after 15 mins). Started with 3000 TPS ,Gradually reduces the TPS count as time moves on.

Comment: Would you pls give me the solution to reduce the CPU utilization n jmeter. And the following is the Heap Size used:${HEAP:="-Xms1g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=4g"}

Comment: What's the CPU utilisation by the JMeter (java process) when the test is executed? You can run the test in non-gui mode, save the test results in CSV format, use only required/minimum assertions , remove unnecessary plugins, generate the test reports at the end, save only required fields in listeners

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all your application must be able to handle such a load. I don't know what your `180000 of throughput,` stanza means,if you put it to the Constant Throughput Timer be aware that:

- it is precise enough on "minute" level
- it can only "pause" JMeter to "limit" its throughput to the given value

  In general you can reach out 3000 TPS with 40 users only if 1 user will make 75 requests per second which means that your application response time should be below 75 milliseconds.

  If response time will be higher - you won't be able to reach 3000 requests per second with 40 users.

2. Also JMeter should be able to send requests fast enough, so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and if this is not sufficient consider using [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

More information: [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second)

Comment: I have used Precise Throughput timer, Throughput value assigned as 180000, So that the expected TPS value is 3000(180000/60).I will calculate the application response time as next step.

Comment: Would you pls give me the solution to reduce the CPU utilization n jmeter. And the following is the Heap Size used:${HEAP:="-Xms1g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=4g"}

Comment: means that your application response time should be below 13 milliseconds.rather than  75